# if one field doesn't exist in the sent object it fails give this error "[parsing_exception] no text specified for text query"

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

```
function getConversations(filter,res){
  client.search({
    index: "conversations",
    type: "docs",
    body: {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [{
              "range": {
                "followers_count": {
                  "gte": filter.followers_count_range.gte,
                  "lte": filter.followers_count_range.lte
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "user_gender": filter.gender
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "dialect": filter.dialect
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "lang": filter.language
              }
            }

          ],

          "minimum_should_match":1

        }
      }

    }

  }, function(err, resp, status) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(400).send({
        message: "Not Found"
      });
    } else {
      //console.log("--- Response ---");
      console.log(resp);
      console.log("--- Hits ---");
      resp.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit) {
        console.log(hit._source);
      });
      res.status(200).send({
        message: "Done"
      });
    }
  });
}
```

I am new to elastic search and need more understanding and help.
if one field of the match doesn't exist in the send object it gives an error why, how can I fix that
if my filter has only a name property  it doesn't work all property must be in the filter obj
another question
if I want to say that if a language is a specific value I choose to neglect to match the dialect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the existence of a given filter before passing it to the ES request body with a ternary operator. If it's falsy, use the [`match_all` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) which is essentially the Elasticsearch equivalent a no-operation:

```js
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      should: [
        {
          range: {
            followers_count: {
              gte: filter.followers_count_range.gte,
              lte: filter.followers_count_range.lte
            }
          }
        },
        filter.gender
          ? {
              match: {
                user_gender: filter.gender
              }
            }
          : {
              match_all: {}
            },
        filter.dialect
          ? {
              match: {
                dialect: filter.dialect
              }
            }
          : {
              match_all: {}
            },
        filter.language
          ? {
              match: {
                lang: filter.language
              }
            }
          : { match_all: {} }
      ],

      minimum_should_match: 1
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can i ask one more question ?   if  `match: {
                user_gender: filter.gender
              }` if filter.gender is an array how to pass it as it gives error "Can't get text on start array "

Comment: I assume `gender` is a boolean field so you can use a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html).